# Foreign Key constraints in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a newbie to PHP. I have been given the code snippet below as homework:

```
CREATE  TABLE `admin_log`   (
`id`    INT(11) NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`statusdate`    DATETIME    DEFAULT NULL,
`type` INT(11) DEFAULT  NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  

)   ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Why will it not be possible to set up any foreign key constraints using this table?

I have done some research on Google and I cant find a reason why foreign key constraints are not possible. Please help

Comment: on which column you want to give foreign key constraint?

Comment: You can't setup foreign keys on columns from this table because it's MyISAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this :

```
CREATE  TABLE `admin_log`   (
`id`    INT(11) NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`statusdate`    DATETIME    DEFAULT NULL,
`type` INT(11) DEFAULT  NULL,

 INDEX (type),
 FOREIGN KEY (type)
    REFERENCES type(id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
)   ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin
```

Notice the engine **INNODB** insetad of **MYISAM** which doesn't permit foreign key.

Or using MySQLAdmin in the "structure" tab, click on the "relationals view" link below the table description.

Comment: Is MyISAM supporting FK at all? AFAIR it doesn't but might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Even it has been mentioned on comment before -- just to make it more prominent: MyISAM is not supporting foreign keys. So you will need to change the engine of your table to e.g. INNODB if possible.